# Call MSBuild passing it a single task to run

Tags: msbuild, csproj

We can define a target in a `csproj` file and then specify that target when we call `msbuild` from the command line. That looks like this:

### `my.csproj`

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination" />
</Target>
```

### `msbuild`

```
msbuild my.csproj /t:CopyFiles
```

The `CopyFiles` targets asks `msbuild` to run the `Copy` task.

What if we don't want to edit the `csproj` file. How can we define a target just from the command line? Alternatively, using only the command line, how can we ask `msbuild` to run just one or maybe two tasks?

### Pseudo-Code

```
msbuild my.csproj /t:"Copy SourceFiles=@(MySourceFiles) DestinationFolder=..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [MSBuild Command-Line Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx), this isn't possible exactly as you describe it, i.e. MSBuild will not take Target definitions from the command-line input. They have to be defined in a file somewhere.

**But**, you can have a script (maybe even a .bat?) that does something like:

1. Create a new, essentially empty, project file.
2. Import the `.csproj`, with `<Import Project="foo.csproj" />`
3. Add the targets
4. Call MSBuild with the new project file with the targets you want. Multiple targets can be specified by multiple `/t:` switches. Properties can be specified with `/p:`

The final, programmatically/script generated project file might look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="foo.csproj" />
  <Target Name="CopyFiles">
  <Copy
    SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
    DestinationFolder="$(Destination)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The actual MSBuild command called might then be:

```
msbuild temp.proj /t:CopyFiles /p:"Destination=c:\MyProject\Destination"
```